# How to add an non aggregated column in a fact table?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I'm working on a SSAS cube to allow user to analyze some sales.
So, I created a fact table to record all sales and few dimensions to browse inside data (category / location & store, etc...).

This is a example of the fact table output (from SQL Server Management Studio) :

[image]

When I browse my cube, I can review all sales including date, quantity, etc.
However, when I add some fields like the "unit price" or the "unit cost", it returns me a strange result probably due to an aggregate behavior.
It seems it return the sum of all matching rows (aggregateFunction property).

How to simply display the unit price of a sale without apply any calculation to the unit price column. The None value for the AttributeFunction display BLANK/NULL.

Comment: What do you want to see for store_id=17 in unitCost? As far as we must choose at least something to show: 77.6 or 239.2?

Comment: I want to display the cost of product where id = 2 not depending on the other parameters. No sum, no calcuation, just the unit cost.
So when I browse the cube I want to instantly see the unit cost / unit price of the product for each sale row. In my SSAS cube, I see a strange calculation or null if I change AggregateFunction to None.

Comment: AVG function will be ok for products, but if we put another dimension to axis we need at least something to show. Let us say we put Seller dimension to axis 0 and measures to axis 1. So, seller John sold 2 items of product_id=2 and 10 items of product_id=3. Another seller Pete sold the same. What do you need to show in measures unitCost and unitPrice if we have no Product dimension on any axis? If this situation is impossible (and only product can be on the axis) feel free to use AVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unitCost and unitPrice are the same for each product (I mean unitCost can be only 77.6 for product_id = 2), you can just use average (or even emulate average by SUM/COUNT) - but only for product dimension on axis!
Another dimensions will show real average values.

Maybe it's better to use this 'static' fields like attribute properties in 'Product' dimension? But you still need to add some logic to choose one value for several (or all) product members selected.